# How to build .aab bundle instead .apk file with react native EXPO locally?

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, android-app-bundle

When I make a local build of an app created using EXPO react native, I get an .apk file instead of .aab

1. For testing app build I am using expo template with expo router

```
npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@50
```

2. Then I do prebuild

```
npx expo prebuild
```

3. I'm following these instructions 
   Production builds locally 
   https://docs.expo.dev/deploy/build-project/#production-builds-locally

   Publishing to Google Play Store 
   https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android
4. I'm generating a key with keytool
5. I'm making changes to the android/gradle.properties file
6. I'm making changes in the android/app/build.gradle  adding signing config
7. And finally I am using this command

```
npx expo run:android --variant release
```

After all this I get app-release.apk file in this folder "\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release"

But how I can get .aab bundle file?

Answer (score 0):

check if your eas.json have

```
"android":{
                        "buildType": "apk"
                    },
```

under the channel you are trying to get your build from.

Comment: I don't have eas.json because  I making build without EAS.  EAS locally build don't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

First go into your project dir in terminal.

1. npm install -g eas-cli (to install eas in windows)
2. Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned (to change permission of eas issue in terminal)
3. eas build (to build aab file)
   eas build -p android --profile preview (to build apk file)

Comment: HI. I don't use EAS, because I have Windows PC.

Comment: but i make build apk file from eas command and i am still using windows pc

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by running:

```
cd ./android
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

This will create `app-release.aab` in `android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release` directory.

Another way is by running:

```
npx react-native build-android --mode=release
```

even though in this [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/deploy/build-project#production-builds-locally), it clearly states that you should use:

```
npx expo run:android --variant release
```

Comment: I was qurious if there is a way to do this using the `expo-cli`. Did someone manage to find a better way?